# What is the syntax of a URL

Tags: url

Can someone explain the syntax of a web addresses URL in layman's terms.

Comment: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)

Answer (score 2):

protocol://subdomain.domain.topLevelDomain:port/path/path.extension?query&morequery=value#fragment for the web mostly.

Or check out [Simple.wikipedia article](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) for a nice layman explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) which describes:

> a Uniform Resource Locator (URL), the
>   syntax and semantics of formalized
>   information for location and access of
>   resources via the Internet.

Here is an extract of the BNF-like description of a http URL:

```
url            = httpurl | ftpurl | newsurl |
                 nntpurl | telneturl | gopherurl |
                 waisurl | mailtourl | fileurl |
                 prosperourl | otherurl

httpurl        = "http://" hostport [ "/" hpath [ "?" search ]]
hpath          = hsegment *[ "/" hsegment ]
hsegment       = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
search         = *[ uchar | ";" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[protocol]://[host/domain name][:port]/[path to resource]

protocol - http, https, ftp, etc
host/domain name - www.example.com, localhost, 192.34.12.1, etc
port - 80 by default for http, can be something else too
path to resource - /images/test.gif, /index.php
```